# Pam LDAP request returns wrong credentials (49)

Tags: ldap, pam

I am trying to set up pam authentification using ldap from Debian jessy to an SLES11 server without success. I always receive a wrong credentials return althoug it can successfully bind usind `ldapsearch`. Following are the ldap log outputs vor the cases I perform:

```
ldapsearch -D uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de -W -H ldap://192.168.100.11 'uid=testuser'

slapd[4628]: conn=1072 fd=18 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.100.12:59539 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd[4628]: conn=1072 op=0 BIND dn="uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1072 op=0 BIND dn="uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
slapd[4628]: conn=1072 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1072 op=1 SRCH base="ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(uid=testuser)"
slapd[4628]: conn=1072 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1072 op=2 UNBIND
slapd[4628]: conn=1072 fd=18 closed
```

---

Login attempt using the following `/etc/pam_ldap.conf`:

```
host 192.168.100.11
base ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de
ldap_version 3
```

Results in

```
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 fd=18 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.100.12:59540 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=1 SRCH base="ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(uid=testuser)"
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=2 BIND dn="uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=2 RESULT tag=97 err=49 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=3 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=3 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=4 BIND dn="uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=4 RESULT tag=97 err=49 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=5 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=5 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 op=6 UNBIND
slapd[4628]: conn=1073 fd=18 closed
```

---

And the login attempt using the following `/etc/pam_ldap.conf`:

```
host 192.168.100.11
base ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de
ldap_version 3
rootbinddn cn=adminaccount,ou=daemonadmins,dc=our-domain,dc=de
```

Results in

```
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 fd=18 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.100.12:59543 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=0 BIND dn="cn=adminaccount,ou=daemonadmins,dc=our-domain,dc=de" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=0 BIND dn="cn=adminaccount,ou=daemonadmins,dc=our-domain,dc=de" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=1 SRCH base="ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(uid=testuser)"
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=2 BIND anonymous mech=implicit ssf=0
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=2 BIND dn="uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=2 RESULT tag=97 err=49 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=3 BIND dn="cn=adminaccount,ou=daemonadmins,dc=our-domain,dc=de" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=3 BIND dn="cn=adminaccount,ou=daemonadmins,dc=our-domain,dc=de" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=3 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=4 BIND anonymous mech=implicit ssf=0
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=4 BIND dn="uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=our-domain,dc=de" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=4 RESULT tag=97 err=49 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=5 BIND dn="cn=adminaccount,ou=daemonadmins,dc=our-domain,dc=de" method=128
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=5 BIND dn="cn=adminaccount,ou=daemonadmins,dc=our-domain,dc=de" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=5 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 op=6 UNBIND
slapd[4628]: conn=1076 fd=18 closed
```

To me it looks like the password is in fact wrong since the search finds the entry. I also tried different settings for the `pam_password` entry in `/etc/pam_ldap.conf` without any visible changes.

**Is there any difference in how `PAM` sends the password to the LDAP server compared to `ldapsearch`?**

Comment: What linux distro do you use?

Comment: @Slipeer Debian 8.4 on the client and SLES11 on the ldap server

Comment: When the broker between LDAP and pam on client is `sssd` (as it is in modern Debians), no, there is no difference in how LDAP passwords are handled. Would you please post your (anonymized) `sssd.conf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem turned out to be the local accounts. I noticed I could log in with an existing local account by providing either its local or the `LDAP` password. In the latter case it would bind successfully on the `LDAP` server.

To allow users without an exising local account I had to install `libpam-mkhomedir` and add it to `/etc/pam.d/common-session` (as well as removing an `ssh` group membership requirement which only specific to my case). Now the login without exising local accounts work.

I can not explain how a missing local account results in an unsuccessful bind on the `LDAP` server since the logs show no explanation for any kind of different behaviour. If someone could share some light on this I would be very interested in finding out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run sshd in debug mode:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d -D -e -p 2222
```

then try to ssh in to trigger the error with:

```
ssh -p 2222 youruser@yourhost
```

Please share the debug log from sshd. This could get us closer what is the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already figured out the issue -> see my own answer